# How can I connect a router on a network but network admins must see as a PC

Tags: router, access-point, pppoe

I am an electronic engineering student. Our internet connection is provided to us with a PPPoE connection in our dormitories. We are connecting to the internet with our user name and password, and there is also a MAC filter. You cannot enter your password on another computer. Here is the question...

I want to connect a router on that network, the router will connect to the internet with my user name. Approximately 3 notebooks and a desktop computer will be connected to this router.
First of all, it is possible or not?

Secondly, will network admins see my router as a computer or a router/access point?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a "Help me sneak forbidden hardware onto the network under my IT department's nose" question.

Comment: I can understand why he would want to do this, this is very common in UK university halls of residence, there broadband is provided by an external supplier and is MAC filtered to prevent you using more than 1 pc on the connection, basically so that everyone in a flat buys a connection each, rather than 1 person buying and sharing it with a wireless router. This causes problems if your doing a techical course and want to run multiple peices of hardware in your room to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others said: you will have to clone the MAC adress. Besides that, if you have a good router, you can turn on "TTL mangling" - this way it will be harder to detect the machines behind the router.

Comment: Have you got any models to suggest?

Comment: I can't check right now but Linksys (Cisco) makes very good routers with firmware based on Linux - most of them have TTL mangling/masking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm puzzled as to why you don't want the admins to know, as it seems like a reasonably legit thing you want to do.  Unless there is something more going on that you haven't told us about, but anyway...

I wouldn't advocate a MAC address cloning/spoofing solution; the admins will likely be able to determine the types of devices connecting to the internet via SNMP queries if they're any way competent, and you could possible end up getting yourself into some trouble with your college authorities.  You don't want that do you?

An alternative approach would be to configure the box that is allowed to connect as a proxy server with some NAT and set up your own private subnet.  But I would really advise that you talk to your admins also.

Comment: Thanks for advise.
Don't be puzzled it just not allowed but i will talk with them...

Answer (score 1):

Very possible.

1. Clone the "authorized" MAC and use with the other devices.
2. Use a router and NAT and clone the authorized MAC address and use it as the router's MAC address. Most routers support this because some ISPs using MAC filtering with their cable modems.

You might want to change the title of your question. It looks like you are asking for "hacking" advice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you will need to tell the Admins the MAC of your router. Technically, that should work. But they likely will get you, as multiple computers will generate a different traffic pattern than a single computer. I would look out for that because there are just too many students like you that are too "clever" for their own good.

Comment: You are saying my only problem is traffic pattern. I think it's not a problem for me. What if i run some virtual PCs on my computer and surf on internet, this causes the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Heres what you do.  Use a old computer with a few pci slots in it.

Get a supported linux pci wireless card

Configure box with linux to be a router.

Install a gui on it to sign into the radius page(sounds like what you have to do).

Connect to the linux router.

???

Profit.

Comment: i think thats my only perfect solution...

Comment: No doubt.  its really simple to do as well honestly.  Its a simple little script that you pop on there at boot and call it good.  I used to have a linux 'router' that hosted all my other services to make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your router can clone the registered system's MAC address and supports PPPoE, it should work just fine.

*Note I said should*.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect one system with a proxy server and second network card for your LAN.